# Which keyboard layout support all acute accent?

Tags: keyboard

Is there any keyboard layout support all the acute accent list in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acute_accent ?

Comment: Have you checked the list of keyboard layouts provided by Apple?

Answer (score 1):

ABC Extended can add Unicode combining acute to anything.  Some fonts will display better than others,